# Devise return incorect user ID?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, devise

I get the error shown below on sign in (via Devise)

Oddly, Rails/Devise seems to be returning a user id of '1' even though there is no user in my users table with an id of '1'.  This seems to happen kind of randomly, I can't figure out what the problem is.

Here's the latest error message.

ODBC::Error: S1000 (9001) [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]The log for database '[redacted]' is not available. Check the event log for related error messages. Resolve any errors and restart the database.: EXEC sp_executesql N'UPDATE [users] SET [last_sign_in_at] = ''2012-11-12T16:58:34.020'', [current_sign_in_at] = ''2012-11-13T08:44:33.586'', [sign_in_count] = 69, [updated_at] = ''2012-11-13T08:44:33.630'' **WHERE [users].[id] = 1;** SELECT @@ROWCOUNT AS AffectedRows'

Here's the request params:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"[redacted]=",
"user"=>{"email"=>"jkramxx@xx.com",
"password"=>"[FILTERED]",
"remember_me"=>"0"},
"commit"=>"Sign in"}
```

There actually is no user in the db with an id of "1", and theres nothing wrong with the server.  The user jkramxx@xx.com has id of 60. ( user id 1 was deleted from the db a while ago).  I thought it might be something in the session cookie so i deleted that as well).

I've seen similar odd behavior in the console, where I have been able to log in, but when I examine current_user in the debugger  it shows the user having an id of '1' even though when I examine the db directly (using SQL Server Mgmt Studio) the user has id of 34 and there is no user with id of 1.  Sometimes this beahvior goes away when I restart the debugger.  All very random.

Any suggestions?

(Ruby 1.9.3./Rails 3.2.8 SQL Server 10 using ruby-obdc gem)

Comment: I think we need more to go on.  There's not too much magic in the `current_user` helper -- at sign_in it looks up a user based on the passed email address and if found confirms that the password matches.  At that point, the current user object is stored in the session.  I would put some logging in various place to see where it is that `current_user` gets updated from the correct one to the incorrect one (`logger.debug "id of current_user is #{current_user.id}"`).  It's not random, of course, but if it's hard to track down, logging code can be there to help you isolate the cause.

Comment: Finally solved this one.  I had set up another very similar  test database with a similar name, and my obdc had that had the wrong database as the initial database.  At some point Rails switched to the right database (the one indicated in database.yml) but I think the first query to the db was going to the wrong db, and thereafter it was going to the live db.  Very confusing, since for the most part the app worked as it should and was interacting with the right database, but on startup it would sometimes look at the wrong db.